# Insert data from a CANoe database to an existing Excel sheet

Tags: excel, capl, canoe, canalyzer

`Recently, I was given a task to automate the process of inserting some data of an ECU in CANoe into an already existing Excel sheet using CAPL. I am fairly new to this and wanted some help. I will be as elaborate as possible.

1. How can I create an link an env var to a database in CAPL/CANoe.
2. I have already creaed a panel with a button that should be assigend with the above asked env var. So, my question here is how can I access an already existing file that needs some data from this button? I mean CAPL does not allow excel format. How can I output some data to an existing excel sheet with the click of a button? How should I proceed to write the code for this?

Comment: Can you add an example code?

Comment: I have added a code for write the buffer to a new file. But I have to write some data to an existing excel file in the below environmental variable. Hope thisi hepls.

Comment: Have you consider .CSV format? It would be simpler to save it in this format,due it is normal text file.

Comment: Yes. But we have to fill out that excel sheet with some other data as well from manual tests to give it to porsche. And excel is how it is done. Like a summary of the things we did for the battery. And cpnverting a CSV file to excel is not recommended because of huge data loss.

Comment: Don't do that with CAPL. Use CAPL to export it into a text file and write a seperate tool that parses that text file and converts it to Excel.

Comment: Okay.  I will try that and will update on what happens next or if I have any doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CAPL has no API to communicate with Excel and/or print to Excel format.

You need to write your library to do it, or use an external script (think a python script, or something else) with a call to `SysExec()` in your CAPL.

To the best of my knowledge, there isn't an opensource solution ready.